# Elasticsearch Java API addMapping() and setSettings() usage

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, mapping

**Problem: How to create an index from a json file using**

The json file contains a definition for the index `de_brochures`. It also defines an analyzer `de_analyzer`with custom filters that are used by the respective index.
As the json works with curl and Sense I assume I have to adapt the syntax of it to work with the java API.

*I don't want to use XContentFactory.jsonBuilder() as the json comes from a file!*

I have the following json file to create my mapping from and to set settings:

Using Sense with PUT /indexname it does create an index from this.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "de_brochures": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true,
          "index_analyzer": "de_analyzer"
        },
        "classification": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "de_stopwords": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_german_"
        },
        "de_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "name": "light_german"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "de_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "de_stopwords",
            "de_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As the above did not work with addMapping() alone I tried to split it into two seperate files (I realized that I had to remove the `"mappings":` and `"settings":` part):

```
------ Mapping json ------
{
  "de_brochures": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true,
        "index_analyzer": "de_analyzer"
      },
      "classification": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "language": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
------- Settings json --------
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "de_stopwords": {
        "type": "stop",
        "stopwords": "_german_"
      },
      "de_stemmer": {
        "type": "stemmer",
        "name": "light_german"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "de_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "de_stopwords",
          "de_stemmer"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my java code to load and add/set the json.

```
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(index);
// CREATE SETTINGS
String settings_json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(brochures_mapping_path));
createIndexRequestBuilder.setSettings(settings_json);
// CREATE MAPPING
String mapping_json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(brochures_mapping_path));
createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping("de_brochures", mapping_json);
CreateIndexResponse indexResponse = createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

There is no more complaint about the mapping file's structure but it now fails with the error:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [de_analyzer] not found for field [text]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**
I managed to do it with my original json file using `createIndexRequestBuilder.setSource(settings_json);`

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question. Solutions aren't questions. Solutions are answers. Stackoverflow encourages self-answering your questions when you find solutions. But please do that in an answer. Editing the question to include the solution just confuses readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with structure of your mapping file.

Here is a sample example.

```
mapping.json
{
"en_brochures": {
    "properties": {
        "text": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true,
            "index_analyzer": "en_analyzer",
            "term_vector": "yes"
        },
        "classification": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "language": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
    }
}



String mapping = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mapping.json")));
    createIndexRequestBuilder.addMapping('en_brochures', mapping);
    CreateIndexResponse indexResponse =createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

This works in mine, you can try.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can fit in the "analyzer" part into your json structure for it to work?

Comment: Look up! I have changed, my answer. And, for this to work you have to add settings (as you did before)

Comment: I assume you already added the en_analyzer? How did you do that?
Otherwise it complains about not finding "en_analyzer" for "text".